# MySQL Workbench - Creating a one-to-one relationship using existing columns?

Tags: mysql, relational-theory

How do I create a one-to-one relationship using existing columns in MySQL Workbench?

I have an EER diagram tab open and I am selecting from the toolbar on the left hand side.

Unfortunately it seems that I can create a one-to-many or many-to-one relationship but not a one-to-one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Right click on the relationship line
- Select 'Edit Relationship'
- Click on the Foreign Key tab in the Relationship Tab
- The Cardinality of the relationship can be changed with the two radio buttons